# Fixed Point of continous map on a closed ball to R^n

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

For a closed ball $\overline{B_R(0)}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $R>0$ we have $f\in C^0(\overline{B_R(0)},\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\langle x,f(x) \rangle\leq \langle x,x \rangle$ for $x \in \partial \overline{B_R(0)}$. Show that $f$ has fixed point.

My guess (I'm very sceptical):
$f$ continuous implies that Im$(f)$ is compact.
\begin{align}
\text{Im}(f)\subset \overline{B_{R_i}(0)} \;\; \text{for} \;\; R_i\geq\!\!\max_{x\in \overline{B_R(0)}}\! ||f(x)||.
\end{align}
If $R>R_i$ I'm done, since I can use Brouwer fixed point theorem.
For $R<R_i$ define $g_i: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, x\mapsto \frac{R}{R_i} x$, so that $g_i\circ f(\overline{B_{R_i}(0)})\subset \overline{B_{R_i}(0)}$ and by Brouwers theorem there exists $x_0$ so that $g_i\circ f(x_0)=x_0$, hence there exists $x_0$ so that $f(x_0)=\frac{R_i}{R}x_0$ is true. But since $R_i$ can chosen arbitrary large, $x_0$ has to be $0$.

Does it work?

Comment: Notice you did not use the inner product assumption. Moreover, $x_0$ depends on $R_i$, but for your final argument to work one must show that the dependence is continuous. Is it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I just realized that the dependence of $x_0$ on $R_i$ is a simple scaling, which denies the final argument, making my reasoning incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try using the following well-known result in fixed point theory:

> **(Leray-Schauder Nonlinear Alternative):** Let $E$ be a Banach space and $C \subset E$ a closed convex set. Let $p \in \text{int}(C)$ and $U\subset C$ be an open set containing $p$. If $f: \overline{U} \longrightarrow C$ is continuous and compat (that is, $\text{Im}(f)$ is contained in a compact of $C$), then either:
>
> $(1)$ $f$ has a fixed point in $\overline{U}$; or
>
> $(2)$ There is some $u \in \partial U \subset C$ and some $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that
>
> $$u=\lambda \cdot f(u) + (1-\lambda)\cdot p$$

What should $E$, $C$, $p$ and $U$ be in your example? Is $f$ compact (duh)? After answering these questions, all you have to do is show that $(2)$ does not apply.